# systemctl start logstash does nothing

Tags: logstash

I am working on pulling changes onto a few Logstash boxes. The issue is when I run the command

```
systemctl start logstash
```

I get nothing back.

Expected:
logstash starts with a verbose output.

Actual:

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `systemctl status logstash` to see the service's status

Or run `journalctl -xe -u logstash` to open a `less` style interface where you'll be able to see any errors/output the logstash service might have thrown while trying to start.